# Position of agent in passive speech

Tags: passive-voice

Which sentence is correct?

> This new house will be bought by him next month.

or

> This new house will be bought next month by him.

I'm considering if there is a difference in meaning between these two sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the usual position of the agent is as the subject of an active sentence:

> He will buy the house next month.

In a passive sentence the agent, if included, can go in either position.  There's no real difference in meaning.  We tend to put long phrases at the end of sentences so if the agent is a complex phrase it would be better at the end:

> ... bought next month by the young gentleman with the top hat and tails.

otherwise it makes sense to put it close to the verb

> ... bought by him next month.